# Unique merging of three array items

Tags: javascript

How can I create a unique combination of all possible merge of these 3 arrays?

```js
var vars1 =['v1-Item1', 'v1-Item2', 'v1-Item3','v1-Item4', 'v1-Item5'];
var vars2 =['v2-Item1', 'v2-Item2', 'v2-Item3','v2-Item4', 'v2-Item5'];
var vars3 =['v3-Item1', 'v3-Item2', 'v3-Item3','v3-Item4', 'v3-Item5'];

for (i = 0; i < vars1.length; i++) { 
    console.log(vars1[i],vars2[i],vars3[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 3 nesting for loops, and push each combination as a sub array to the `result` array:

```js
var vars1 =['v1-Item1', 'v1-Item2', 'v1-Item3','v1-Item4', 'v1-Item5'];
var vars2 =['v2-Item1', 'v2-Item2', 'v2-Item3','v2-Item4', 'v2-Item5'];
var vars3 =['v3-Item1', 'v3-Item2', 'v3-Item3','v3-Item4', 'v3-Item5'];

var result = [];

for (i = 0; i < vars1.length; i++) { 
  for (j = 0; j < vars2.length; j++) { 
    for (k = 0; k < vars3.length; k++) { 
      result.push([vars1[i], vars2[j], vars3[k]]);
    }
  }   
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to get a random key from each array

```
let arrs = {};
arrs.vars1 =['v1-Item1', 'v1-Item2', 'v1-Item3','v1-Item4', 'v1-Item5'];
arrs.vars2 =['v2-Item1', 'v2-Item2', 'v2-Item3','v2-Item4', 'v2-Item5'];
arrs.vars3 =['v3-Item1', 'v3-Item2', 'v3-Item3','v3-Item4', 'v3-Item5'];


let res = []

for(let i = 0; i < arrs.vars1.length; i++){
 res.push(arrs['vars' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1)][i]);
} 
console.log(res);
```